# Informix function returns without reason

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

So I have the following informix procedure

```
CREATE FUNCTION selectSollmandant(INOUT sollmandat SOLLMANDAT_ROW, inkassodatum INT8) RETURNING SMALLINT
DEFINE ret SMALLINT;
LET ret = 0;
trace "Entering select sollmandat " || sollmandat.vers_schein_nr;

PREPARE sollStmt FROM "SELECT s::SOLLMANDAT_ROW FROM  sollmandat s WHERE vers_schein_nr = ? ORDER BY lfdnr desc";

DECLARE _sollmCsr CURSOR FOR sollStmt;
IF SQLCODE != 0 THEN
    CALL print_to_proto("DECLARE letztZahlCsr " || SQLCODE);
    RETURN 0;
END IF;

TRACE "log ===========  1";
OPEN _sollmCsr USING sollmandat.vers_schein_nr;
TRACE "log ===========  2" || SQLCODE;

IF SQLCODE != 0 THEN
    TRACE "log ===========  3" || SQLCODE;  
    CALL print_to_proto("OPEN sollmandat " || SQLCODE);
    RETURN 0;
END IF;
TRACE "sollmandant iban is ===========  4" || SQLCODE;  
WHILE (1=1) LOOP .... end loop and return...
```

Problem is that my function returns before reaching the while loop and it never hits log2, log 3 or log 4.

Can you please help me? I don't see what I am missing.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which version of Informix, running on which platform?  Are we to assume that the code does reach `log 1` but not the later log messages?  The `SELECT s::SOLLMANDAT_ROW FROM …` notation is puzzling.  What do you think it does?  Did you mean `s.SOLLMANDAT_ROW`?    You've no error trapping (ON EXCEPTION), so if the OPEN fails because of this, you'd not see the `log 2` message,

Comment: Oh, ugh — you've need to provide an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It looks like SOLLMANDAT_ROW may be some UDT in the database.  But you've not shown us what it is.  You've not shown the structure of the `sollmandat` table.  You've not provided us with what's necessary to make this work on our systems.  Have you run the SQL on its own — the SELECT statement should be runnable in DB-Access, I think.  Your code has me 100% confused (which takes some doing).  Please provide us with the MCVE.  Are you expecting to iterate over a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue, but before I get into how i did it I want to try and clarify what the above posted code means actually.

## CLARIFICATION

Ok so the `SOLLMANDAT_ROW` is a `ROW_TYPE`  that I defined (think of it a `struct` like data object for stored procedures). The above mentioned function  is part of a big a big UDR and we use data row for easier data manipulation. The function should select some row out of my `sollmadant` table and store the row in my custom defined `SOLLMANDAT_ROW`.

In order to be able to store the selected rows in ROW_TYPES, the row must be explicilty casted to the that specific row type, hence the syntax `SELECT s::SOLLMANDAT_ROW FROM...`.

## ACTUAL SOLUTION

It turned out that the problem was cursor relate, you see , in the context in which i was running the function, the queried table was a **synonym**, and my code was breaking at the `OPEN cursor` statement. **What I did in order to get pass the issue was to refer to my row data like this:**

```
SELECT ROW([row colums gere ])::SOLLMANDAT_ROW [rest of select statement]
```

After making this change, the function is behaving as it should.

I don't really know why informix does not "like" the syntax of my first select when trying to store rows from synonym tables into specific custom row types. And if anybody can provide a explanation I would be very grateful.

I hope this post will be helpful to others, and I thank you for your time.

Comment: Created a couple of similar (very simple) procedures in Informix version 12.10.FC9DE and I had no problem with the `ROW` casts. Could you provide your Informix version? And what SQL + ISAM errors are being returned? Or provide a MCVE like Jonathan asked.

Comment: Hello- there were no SQL +ISAM errors returned and informix version si 11.70.

Comment: There should be an exception being raised when the cursor is `OPEN`. But it is probably being caught somewhere in that big UDR you mention. Try what Jonathan wrote in is 1st comment, place an `ON EXCEPTION` in that particular procedure, using the `SET` clause to capture the error and write it out with `TRACE`.